Using chain rule to find a partial derivative
I'm currently studying for the math GRE and this question was on one of the recent practice exams. I will restate the full question below, then provide my solution.
Let $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ be real-valued differentiable functions that are implicitly defined by the equations $x = f(u,v)$ and $y = g(u,v)$, where $f$ and $g$ are real-valued differentiable functions. Which of the following is an expression for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ ?
Here is my solution. I say that $x = f(u(x,y),v(x,y))$ and $y = g(u(x,y),v(x,y))$. Then I take the mixed partials using chain rule to get that $$\begin{align}&1 = f_uu_x + f_vv_x\quad\quad 0 =f_uu_y + f_vv_y\\ & 0 = g_uu_x+g_vv_x\quad\quad 1 = g_uu_y + g_vv_y\end{align}$$
Then I realize this looks like an identity matrix as the product of two matrices so I do some unscrambling to get that $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}f_u & f_v \\ g_u & g_v\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_x & u_y \\ v_x & v_y\end{bmatrix}$$
and assuming invertibility I get that $$\begin{bmatrix}u_x & u_y \\ v_x & v_y\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{f_ug_v - f_vg_u}\begin{bmatrix}g_v & -f_v\\ -g_u & f_u\end{bmatrix}$$
Which tells me that $u_x = \frac{g_v}{f_ug_v - f_vg_u}$, which is indeed the correct answer.
What I'm looking for is to actually know what I did. I barely stumbled to this answer, and feel like I wouldn't have been able to come up with this solution under the time restraints of the exam. Is there some theory or book/chapter I should read to get a better understanding of the chain rule? I've read the section on it from Stewart's textbook, but I feel like I'm not getting the whole picture. I know a Jacobian is something that exists and I feel like it's related to this somehow...

$
\def\q{\quad}
\def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\mb#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Consider the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation in matrix-vector form
$$\eqalign{
x &= \m{x\\y},\q u = \m{u\\v}
\qiq
A = \grad xu
 = \mb{
\grad xu & \grad xv \\\hline
\grad yu & \grad yv \\
},\q
A^{-1}
 = \mb{
\grad ux & \grad uy \\\hline
\grad vx & \grad vy \\
}
}$$
Recall the closed-form expressions for the determinant and inverse of a $2\times 2$ matrix
$$\eqalign{
A &= \mb{a&c\\\hline b&d},\qq A^{-1} = \frac1{\det(A)}\mb{d&-c\\\hline-b&a},\qq \det(A)=ad-bc \\
}$$
Thus the $(1,1)$ component of $A^{-1}$ is exactly the expression that you derived.
